# What is differance between linux kernel versions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wondered what is differance between linux kernel versions? I mean what is it mean for example kernel 3.15.2

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with programming. 
Please read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Are you looking for a changelog, a listing of the changes made to a document/application/etc.? If so, [this](http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxChanges) will probably be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Linus Torvalds supervises code changes and releases to the latest kernel versions, he has delegated the maintenance of older versions to other programmers.

more information : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel

if you download kernel :kernel.org